# AS3: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I'm freaking out. Searched the web for an hour, nothing helped. I'm trying to load PHP data to flash, but it doesn't work. Here's the as3 code:

```
var adressS:URLRequest = new   URLRequest("adress/file.php");

var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        adressS.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        scriptLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 
        scriptLoader.load(adressS);

        scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
        scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);

        function handleLoadSuccessful(e:Event):void {
            if(scriptLoader.data.resulte == "wrong") {
                error_mc.visible = true;
                    error_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
            } else { ... }
```

And here's PHP:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    echo 'resulte='.'wrong';
}
?>
```

I get

> resulte=wrong

from php, so i guess it's not the problem, but when i try to run flash file, i get output error:

> Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
>       at Error$/throwError()
>       at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
>       at flash.net::URLVariables$iinit()
>       at flash.net::URLLoader/flash.net:URLLoader::onComplete()

I have no idea what am i doing wrong.

Please, help.

Comment: Does the PHP file have BOM or other invisible characters

Comment: Perhaps it could be because you set adressS.method = URLRequestMethod.POST but you don't post any values in your request? If you don't send any values, using flash.net.URLVariables, there is probably no need to specify method = POST, right?

Comment: Have you tried using `URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT` and then tracing the output to make sure you're getting what you think you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
scriptLoader.dataFormat = 'variables';
```

// bug with flash, killed me for couple of hours.